# How to scrape more slowly using delay python code

Tags: python

I am making a web **scraper** that has a loop that goes from page to page. The only problem is that it is running too fast and I got temporarily banned from the website. (The website allows robots to access their content).

Is there any library/command that I can add to my code to make it run slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will make your code sleep for 1 second.

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Also, you can use AsyncIO.